# Build a webhook sender in php and a receiver in python

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, webhooks, shared-hosting

I have a shared web host running on Linux and cpanel , I was looking for a way to communicate from my website to a python console on my PC. I've seen that there's a "webhook listener" module for python which seems to be the solution to my problem but I don't know how to build a php webhook sender neither how to make python always listen to that webhook . How can I achieve this ?

Comment: A webhook generally requires a url that can be called on the public Internet so that data can be pushed in realtime. I would imagine that the Python webhook listener is for when your script is implementing a web service in the cloud or something.

Comment: Okay so for the purpose of "reaching a local python console from a website (php)" what methods is available ?

Comment: The external website will never be able to reach your python console, unless your python script is a server by itself and your computer ports are open for external access. Other option is to have the python script poll the php script. Not good on terms of server loads, but it might do the trick for you.

Comment: The easiest way to get data from a website to a console app is to add a script to your website that will look for changes and return them. Your console app would simply poll the website, but it wouldn't be a realtime push kind of thing. This is good for every 5 minute kind of activity, and less good for every second kind of activity. You might instead install a message queuing system on your VPS, such as RabbitMQ which would do a better job if near realtime is a requirement.

Comment: yes the idea that python polls website will do the trick for me @Maarten Veerman .

Comment: but i need to query it every second which i think isn't good for server as @Mark Rabjohn also mentioned , but aren't web servers made for this ?

Comment: When you're talking about polling every second, then the entire construction and speed of your software/hardware stack is in question. If you have your own VPS and you know you are serving say 50 live users max. and you know that the web app/web server and database can reliably respond within 20ms, then go for it, however the solution is not scalable. Without a push solution, to double to 100 users would require an overally doubling of speed, and everything gets a lot more difficult - if it's just one user (one connector) then go for it.

Comment: Thanks for your complete guidance through this @Mark Rabjohn